# $|supp(v)|=0$ implies the existence of $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{|\theta -\phi|>\epsilon}\cot{(\pi(\theta-\phi))}dv(\phi)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $v$ be a complex Borel measure on $[0,1]$ and $m$ be the Lebesgue measure. We define the support of measure by 
$$supp(v) = [0,1]-\cup\{I
\subset [0,1]: v(I)=0\}$$
where $I$ is an interval.

> Suppose that $m(\{supp(v)\})=0$. Show that for a.e. $\theta \in [0,1]$ the following limit exists.
>   $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{|\theta -\phi|>\epsilon}\cot{(\pi(\theta-\phi))}dv(\phi)$$

The cotangent has a good cancellation property but it seems to be hard to use it because $v$ is not translation-invariant. I can't progress any more. I need your help.